# Matlab saving without losing previous iteration's value

Tags: matlab

i'm trying to save values of iterations in a loop. After this function, they will execute other functions before coming to the next iteration. But the problem i'm facing is, it overwrites them and bcomes 000000. Only the last iteration values are seen. How can i fix it ? Is there a way not to use the same variable and save them ? i read about append but will have to use different var name n is not really nice to do so.

```
function DistanceMatrix(iteration,distance_row)
    load('data.mat','oridata')
    load('centroids.mat','centroids') 
        for i = distance_row:(distance_row+3)
            for j=1:300 %no.genes
              total=0;
                  for k=1:6
                      total=total+((oridata(j,k)- centroids(i,k))^2);
                  end
              DistMatrix_Val(i,j)=sqrt(total);
            end  
        end
        save('DistanceMatrix.mat','DistMatrix_Val')
        DistMatrix_Val;
     GroupMatrix(iteration,distance_row)
end
```

[image]

This is the output. I WOULD LIKE TO STORE ALL ITERATION's value and not overwrite them. Can any1 help ?

Comment: Which variable do you want to keep?

Comment: DistMatrix_Val . I have 4x300 in each iteration

Comment: Each time you save DistMatrix, you save the current content of the variable. Since you don't change the file name, the resulting file stores only the last iteration. Try save the variable in a different file each iteration, or build a 3Darray to keep the whole thing before saving it.

Comment: But aside from this function, i'll be calling other functions before moving to next iteration. So it's impossible for me to do all iterations at once. I will also need to load the filename in other functions. How can i store with different filename in a loop like . this ? Sorry i'm not really good with Matlab. Still consider myself a beginner

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK. Use

```
load('DistanceMatrix.mat','DistMatrix_Val')
```

or

```
persistent DistMatrix_Val
```

just before the first `load` command you showed to us.

Comment: ????? The 61 is my last iteration's value. There are 12 iterations in total. After each iteration ( 4 rows, i skip 1 row to differentiate another iteration value )

Comment: Ok. Next time, please also show to us the lines calling `DistanceMatrix`. My Cristal ball has unfortunately some limits.

Comment: Hahaha... Thanks. Works now. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you should do:

```
functon DistanceMatrix = DistanceMatrix(iteration,distance_row)
```

Rather than saving the variable at the end of the function, you return it.

After returning it you can include the variable in a bigger variable (for example a three dimensional Nx4x300 matrix)

If neccesary you can then save it at the end.